# How to transform this into a DLL

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, dll, user-controls, class-library

I want to compile a DLL control, is a Extended Panel but I only have the class, I don't like to use classes for add a custom control, i prefer to add the DLL into the toolbox.

Someone can help me to transform this into a class library DLL control?

PS: In addition maybe I can need a guide-step to make the class-library too, it's my first time trying this.

Thankyou.

```
Imports System
Imports System.Collections.Generic
Imports System.ComponentModel
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Drawing
Imports System.Drawing.Drawing2D
Imports System.Text
Imports System.Windows.Forms

Namespace GradientPanel
    Public Partial Class GradientPanel
        Inherits System.Windows.Forms.Panel

        ' member variables
        Private mStartColor As System.Drawing.Color
        Private mEndColor As System.Drawing.Color

        Public Sub New()
            ' InitializeComponent()
            PaintGradient()
        End Sub

        Protected Overrides Sub OnPaint(pe As PaintEventArgs)
            ' TODO: Add custom paint code here

            ' Calling the base class OnPaint
            MyBase.OnPaint(pe)
        End Sub


        Public Property PageStartColor() As System.Drawing.Color
            Get
                Return mStartColor
            End Get
            Set
                mStartColor = value
                PaintGradient()
            End Set
        End Property


        Public Property PageEndColor() As System.Drawing.Color
            Get
                Return mEndColor
            End Get
            Set
                mEndColor = value
                PaintGradient()
            End Set
        End Property


        Private Sub PaintGradient()
            Dim gradBrush As System.Drawing.Drawing2D.LinearGradientBrush
            gradBrush = New System.Drawing.Drawing2D.LinearGradientBrush(New Point(0, 0), New Point(Me.Width, Me.Height), PageStartColor, PageEndColor)

            Dim bmp As New Bitmap(Me.Width, Me.Height)

            Dim g As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bmp)
            g.FillRectangle(gradBrush, New Rectangle(0, 0, Me.Width, Me.Height))
            Me.BackgroundImage = bmp
            Me.BackgroundImageLayout = ImageLayout.Stretch
        End Sub

    End Class
End Namespace
```

Comment: Hope this link may help you : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7h62478z(v=vs.100).aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have always just used a CustomControlLibrary Name it and set the Assembly Name and Default Namespace to what you want the dll to be, you will then right click on the project and select  add class then you will add your Custom Control's Class Code to the the Project. You can also add a new UserControl at that time. When you compile it, it will create a dll that you can browse to by right clicking on your ToolBox selecting choose items then Browse to your Dll that was created. It will then add the Controls that are contained in your Control Library to your ToolBox.

Comment: Thanks for comment, the problem is I was stupid, I was trying to do it in a "Class Library" project, but I'll need to make it in a "Windows Forms Control Library" project lol, now is all good, thanks again